# What Schwalbe Nobby Nic should I buy?

Tags: tire, mountain-bike, folding-bicycle

I recently bought a [Swissbike X5](http://swissbike.co.uk/montague-x5-paratrooper---p34/) (same as the Montague Paratrooper, but labeled Swissbike and matte black).

It came with Kenda Kinetics 26" x 1.95" (front and rear)  that I'd like to replace.

Due to good experiences with Schwalbe, I'd like to buy the Nobby Nic, but there are many different Nobby Nic models, as well as widths.

I'm going to use the bike mainly for fun riding in the forest.

Comment: It might also help you get answers if you indicate the tire size/width you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with something in the 26x2.25 range with the Double-Defense protection.  The 2.25 will give you nice volume to allow lower pressures while still being narrow enough to fit most frames (you might have to go narrower if your frame won't allow the 2.25).

Double defense will give you the maximum protection, it weighs more, but I doubt you would notice unless racing.

Unless you are well versed in running tubeless, I would just stick with tubes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it might help others if you could expand on why you're recommending against tubeless tires, as people seem to ask about it every so often.

Comment: Tubeless tires require a level of investment that many, including myself are not ready to buy into. Because you are removing the tube from the equation, you have to make sure the tire and wheel can hold the air on their own.  That often requires special tire, wheel and sealant (to fill in any little holes that happen).  You also have to have a plan to deal with flats on the trail.  Tubeless does allow you to run lower pressures (for better traction) and can often self-seal around holes that would flatten a tube.